# extract noun phrase "String" from a stanford constituency parse tree

Tags: stanford-nlp, text-parsing, string-parsing

How can I extract noun phrase `String / Text` without the `POS tags` from a constituency parse tree.

I am able to extract noun phrases without parsing annotations but unable to find a way to extract just the text of that noun phrase.
For Example :

```
String some_sentence = "The dog ran after the intruding bigger dog";
parse Tree :**(ROOT (S (NP (DT The) (NN dog)) (VP (VBD ran) (PP (IN after) (NP (DT the) (JJ intruding) (JJR bigger) (NN dog))))))
```

I can extract the following noun phrases out of this parse tree `(NP (DT The) (NN dog))" and "(NP (DT the) (JJ intruding)` but I need just the text of these noun phrases as *The dog" and "the intruding*.

I have tried to construct the phrases by using `yieldWords()` method of Tree class but it does not guaranty the exact reproduction of the source string as there can be issues with spaces, symbols etc..

Is there a way to get exact source string from the Parse tree ??

Comment: Are you using the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline or the Stanford Parser directly?

Comment: I am using Stanford CoreNLP pipeline for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Once you've extracted a list of yield words using `Tree.yieldWords`, you can generate the original sentence substring with [`Sentence.listToOriginalTextString`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/Sentence.html#listToOriginalTextString-java.util.List-).

I believe this method is new in CoreNLP 3.5.2, so make sure you have the latest version installed.